# Frequency of a given prime gap knowing it occurs infinitely often

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose a given prime gap  $ k $ where  $ k $ is an even positive integer occurs infinitely often, that is, one has  $ p_{n+1}-p_{n}=k $ for infinitely many values of  $ n $. Does it suffice to entail that the density of such primes  $ p_{n} $ below  $ x $ is  $ \asymp\dfrac{x}{\ln^{2}x} $?

Comment: What have you tried in solving this?  What references have you checked?  What in the prime number theorem might related to your question?

Comment: Actually my idea is that all primes gaps give rise to the same order of growth of the considered density as a function of x, the involved constant being expressible in terms of those gaps. Summing the  densities for the $ \log x $ first even numbers as candidates for prime gaps should give a total density of 1 among all primes, hence this "order of growth" should be roughly  $ \frac{\pi(x)}{\log x}\sim\frac{x}{\log^{2} x} $.

Comment: In other words, what matters is not the precise value of a prime gap, but the fact that it is the difference between consecutive primes.